# how to merge tow pandas series to table

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have 2 Pandas series:

First

```
A 91    
P 7
F 281
M 54
```

Second

```
A 107
P 3
F 290
M 51
```

I want to combine them so they look like this:

```
A 91 107
P 7 3
F 281 290
M 54 51
```

With null if index not found.

Comment: Please post the sample code that you have already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html) for this:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2], axis = 1)

    First  Second
A     91     107
P      7       3
F    281     290
M     54      51
```

This will set to `NaN` the values from rows with non-shared index, given that by default it performs an *outer* join. Here's an example:

```
print(df1)
    First
A     91
P      7
D      4
F    281
M     54

print(df2)
    Second
A     107
P       3
F     290
M      51
X      20

pd.concat([df1,df2], axis = 1, sort=False)

   First  Second
A   91.0   107.0
P    7.0     3.0
D    4.0     NaN
F  281.0   290.0
M   54.0    51.0
X    NaN    20.0
```